# PySpark query one column name with the value present in another column

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, pyspark, aws-glue-spark

**Input_pyspark_dataframe:**

```
id   name  collection  student.1.price  student.2.price  student.3.price
111  aaa      1           100              999               232
222  bbb      2           200              888               656
333  ccc      1           300              777               454
444  ddd      1           400              666               787
```

**output_pyspark_dataframe**

```
id   name  collection    price  
111  aaa      1           100           
222  bbb      2           888            
333  ccc      1           300             
444  ddd      3           787
```

**we can find the correct price of each id by using value present in the collection column**

**Question**

using pyspark, How i can find the correct price of each id by dynamically framing column name `student.{collection}.price`  ?

please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

A bit complete but you can do this way.

The `fields` will give you the field names of the struct field, `student`. You should give this manually and eventually get `1, 2, 3`.

The first line then make an array of the columns `student.{i}.price` for `i = range(1, 4)`. Similarly, the second line make an array of the literals `{i}`.

Now, zip this two array into one array such as

```
[('1', col('student.1.price')), ...]
```

and explode the array then it becomes:

```
('1', col('student.1.price'))
('2', col('student.2.price'))
('3', col('student.3.price'))
```

Since the `arrays_zip` give you an array of struct, the above result is struct type. Get each value by using struct key as the column, that is the `index` and `price`.

Finally, you can compare the `collection` and `index` (this is actually the field name of the student struct column).

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

fields = [field.name for field in next(field for field in df.schema.fields if field.name == 'student').dataType.fields]

df.withColumn('array', f.array(*map(lambda x: 'student.' + x + '.price', fields))) \
  .withColumn('index', f.array(*map(lambda x: f.lit(x), fields))) \
  .withColumn('zip', f.arrays_zip('index', 'array')) \
  .withColumn('zip', f.explode('zip')) \
  .withColumn('index', f.col('zip.index')) \
  .withColumn('price', f.col('zip.array')) \
  .filter('collection = index') \
  .select('id', 'name', 'collection', 'price') \
  .show(10, False)

+---+----+----------+-----+
|id |name|collection|price|
+---+----+----------+-----+
|111|aaa |1         |100  |
|222|bbb |2         |888  |
|333|ccc |1         |300  |
|444|ddd |3         |787  |
+---+----+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Hi lamanus, it is a bit complicated, can you please explain it.

Comment: Or if there is another way of dealing the issue , please let me know